# Are Cull Obsidian and Corvus Glaive biological brothers in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Cull Obsidian (Black Dwarf) and Corvus Glaive are biologically brothers in the comics, Earth-616, but it's not clear if this holds true in the MCU as well, especially with a name change. Things like the fandom page take it as granted, however.

> Cull Obsidian and Corvus Glaive were members of a world destroyed by Thanos in his quest to wipe out half the universe. Thanos took the two brothers and raised him as his own children, training them to be deadly members of the Black Order.
>
> <sub>[Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki, Cull Obsidian, Biography, Becoming a Child of Thanos](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Cull_Obsidian)</sub>

> Corvus Glaive and his brother Cull Obsidian were members of a world destroyed by Thanos in his quest to wipe out half the universe. Thanos took the orphaned Glaive and Obsidian and raised them as his own children, training them to be deadly members of the Black Order.
>
> <sub>[Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki, Corvus Glaive, Biography, Following Thanos](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Corvus_Glaive)</sub>

The citation for that point is [‘Avengers: Infinity War’ Directors Compare Thanos to Genghis Khan](https://community.fandom.com/wiki/Articles/avengers-infinity-war-directors-compare-thanos-to-genghis-khan) on both of them which leads to a 404. However, it appears to point to [this article](https://www.fandom.com/articles/avengers-infinity-war-directors-compare-thanos-to-genghis-khan) of the same name. The relevant section in that article is the below which only mentions them being taken from their home planets to become the Children of Thanos, not that these two are brothers:

> “He then collects orphans from each race that he’s conquered. These are called the Children of Thanos. Some of them, like Gamora and Nebula, have broken free from the Cult of Thanos. His cult of personality. Others, like Ebony Maw, celebrate and are the greatest acolytes of Thanos.”
>
> <sub>[Fandom Articles, ‘Avengers: Infinity War’ Directors Compare Thanos to Genghis Khan](https://www.fandom.com/articles/avengers-infinity-war-directors-compare-thanos-to-genghis-khan)</sub>

**Are Cull Obsidian and Corvus Glaive biological brothers in the MCU?**

Comment: They don't look alike. Cull is swole to the max and Corvus looks like he forgot to eat breakfast, lunch *and* dinner. Also their surnames are different

Comment: Arnie and Danny Devito don't [look alike either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twins_(1988_film)) and surnames are such a human centric concept.

Comment: I mean they don't look alike in the comics either where they are biological brothers so I don't think we can really rely on looks here.